# how to write Room Dao query to search unique data based on optional mulitple coulmns in single table in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-room

I have 5 Edit input fields for filtering, user can provide input in any of the Edit fields out of 5. Based on user inputs, how can I use a Room single query to filter a unique row in a single table on button click for android?

tried this gives me multiple values passing the criteria, I want unique values

```
@Query("SELECT * from TBL_PHYSICAL_COUNT_LIST where ((SUBINV IS NOT NULL AND SUBINV != '') AND SUBINV=(:subInv)) OR ((LOCATOR IS NOT NULL AND LOCATOR != '') AND LOCATOR=(:locatorNumber)) OR ((ITEMNUMBER IS NOT NULL AND trim(ITEMNUMBER) > '') AND ITEMNUMBER=(:itemNumber))  OR ((LOTNUMBER IS NOT NULL AND LOTNUMBER != '') AND LOTNUMBER=(:lotNumber)) OR ((TAGNUMBER IS NOT NULL AND trim(TAGNUMBER) <> '') AND TAGNUMBER=(:tagNumber))")
List<TBL_PHYSICAL_COUNT_LIST> getTblPhysicalCountListByFilter(String subInv,String locatorNumber,String itemNumber,String lotNumber,String tagNumber) ;
```

FOR EG: say I enter tagnumber '0601' and item number='1000004', the query should return 1st element in an image, another eg say the user selects subInventory='Accessorie', locatorNumber='2',lotnumber='2010, the query should return 2nd element in the image and so based on user input I want 1 query that should ignore blank input and filter based on provided input.

[image]/

Comment: `gives me multiple values passing the criteria, I want unique values` - instead of this text show some examples with rows you have, rows you get with your query passing the criteria (multiple values) and row(s) you want to get (unique values) with the same criteria. Your problem is hard to understand without that

Comment: for eg: say i enter tagnumber '0601' and item number='1000004', the query should return 1st element in the image, another eg, say the user selects subInventory='Accessorie', locatorNumber='2',lotnumber='2010, the query should return 2nd element in the image and so based on user input I want 1 query that should ignore blank input and filter based on provided input.

Comment: It seems the query should work like you want. And you want to tell that all the time query's returning values don't depend on parameters' values? Can it be that problem not in the query, but in the way how you get updated query's results (in the route from Room to Activity/Fragment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by updating the query like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * from TBL_PHYSICAL_COUNT_LIST " +
            "where (:subInv IS NOT NULL AND SUBINV LIKE :subInv || '%') " +
            "AND (:locatorNumber IS NOT NULL AND LOCATOR LIKE :locatorNumber || '%') " +
            "AND (:itemNumber IS NOT NULL AND ITEMNUMBER LIKE :itemNumber || '%') " +
            "AND (:lotNumber IS NOT NULL AND LOTNUMBER LIKE  :lotNumber || '%') " +
            "AND (:tagNumber IS NOT NULL AND TAGNUMBER LIKE  :tagNumber || '%') ")
List<TBL_PHYSICAL_COUNT_LIST> getTblPhysicalCountListByFilter(String subInv,
                                                                  String locatorNumber,
                                                                  String itemNumber,
                                                                  String lotNumber,
                                                                  String tagNumber);
```